# Windows Collation error occured when deployed window 2012

Tags: sql-server, collation

My question might have the same title as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823849/sql-collation-issues-when-deploying-live): *Sql collation issues when deploying live*. However that question is 8 years old and talks about issue on different sql server.

My infos as below:

- SQL Server is Turkish_100_CI_AI [Windows Collation Name (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/windows-collation-name-transact-sql)
- DB is Turkish_CI_AS ([SQL Server Collation Name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/sql-server-collation-name-transact-sql)):

and

- dev env: windows 8
- test env: windows 2012

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3861782/492258) question:

```
Select City COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS Place, State, Country FROM DEPT1
UNION ALL
Select '' AS Place, 'Arizona' As State, Country FROM DEPT2
```

works properly on sql server.

Problem occurs when deployed to test server with the same connection string (to the same db)
So I can guess the issue related windows os differences only.

Error message is:

> Implicit conversion of varchar value to varchar cannot be performed because the collation of the value is unresolved due to a collation conflict between "Turkish_CI_AS" and "Turkish_100_CI_AI" in UNION ALL operator.

When I run my UNION sql query.

What can be cause and how can I handle given error, in context of changing windows os only?

**EDIT**: Closing question as the colleague informs that db are not the same, so question is no more valid

Comment: What's the collation of `tempdb`?

Comment: Same as sql server: `Turkish_100_CI_AI`

Comment: What is you COLUMN City collation? If you didn't change it, it should have the same collation as db collation, and you don't need to use COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT at all. There is no temporary objects in your query and it should perform well if column collation = db collation

Answer (score 0):

Please execute this query in both environments:

```
select COLUMNPROPERTYEX(object_id('dbo.DEPT1'), 'City', 'Collation') as column_collation,
       DATABASEPROPERTYEX(db_name(), 'Collation') as db_collation, db_name() as db_name;
```

If you get the error for the exact query from your question the difference is between your column collation and database collation.

If you did not define explicitly the column collation it's inherited from database collation, and there is no need to COLLATE at all when you execute your query WHITHIN THAT DATABASE.

If instead your query is executed in the context of another database, or you use temporary tables (that are created with the collation of tempdb) then you need to use COLLATE.

So please check one more time your db collation, your column collation, and the database(maybe your query is executed in another database then you think)

Comment: As noted in question, db env is the same. the only diff is iis so the os

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak Can you please update your post with the result of my query and with your query that executes with the error, both as pictures?

Comment: The run result: `Turkish_CI_AS Turkish_CI_AS SPCMS`

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak and for DEPT2?

Comment: The same result

Comment: Can you post your query that gets an error as image? I think it cannot be the same as in another post. I need to see exact query and exact error